# Progress Bar not disappearing even if WebView is fully loaded

Tags: android, webview

I've implemented a progress bar using the example provided by Android Devs ([This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)) and it doesn't seem to disappear even though the WebView seems to be fully loaded and it stays there after leaving the page.

I want the progress bar (that is a spinner) to be shown every time a URL is being loaded.

I'm very new to this so please be gentle!

The Logcat is constantly outputting this:
`12-13 23:12:42.092    1630-1674/se.welovecode.tismatapp E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44 
 12-13 23:12:42.105    1630-1674/se.welovecode.tismatapp E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0 
 12-13 23:12:42.125    1630-1674/se.welovecode.tismatapp E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)`

My MainActivity:`

```
package se.welovecode.tismatapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView myWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.welovecode.se/t-matapp");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            }
        });

        final Activity activity = this;
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're simply mis-adjusting the progress value.

`WebChromeClient` reports progress [as a percentage, in the 0-100 range](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int%29).

> newProgress - Current page loading progress, represented by an integer
>   between 0 and 100.

Meanwhile, setProgress() expects [a number in the 0-10000 range](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgress%28int%29).

> The progress for the progress bar. Valid ranges are from 0 to 10000
>   (both inclusive). *If 10000 is given, the progress bar will be
>   completely filled and will fade out*.

Therefore, you should multiply by 100, not 1000.

```
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
    }
```

Comment: Well the progress bar isn't showing all the time anymore, but now I can't tell if it's working properly cause my internet connection is so good

Comment: Okay, noticed I messed up the progressbar in my XML and noticed now that this did not fix it.